# Swift : CABasicAnimation Issue

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cabasicanimation

The code you see below creates a CALayer (rectangle shape) and animates it from the left to the right when the user holds down on the screen`longPressGestureRecognizer`. When they lift their finger, the CALayer stops animating, it gets pushed into an array, and when they hold on the screen again another CALayer is created. You can copy and paste code directly in new project:

```
 //Global Variables
var layer: CALayer?
var holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
var layerHolder = [CALayer]()
var endPoint : CGFloat = 0


func setUpView(){

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)
    holdGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleLongPress:")

}


func handleLongPress(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    print("inside handlelong press")

    let newLayer = CALayer()

    if(sender.state == .Began) {

        newLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 10)
        newLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        if(layerHolder.count >= 1){
            newLayer.frame.origin.x = endPoint
        }

        animation.fromValue = endPoint
        animation.toValue = self.view.bounds.width * 2
        animation.duration = 30
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)

        print("Long Press Began")
        newLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "bounds.size.width")

        layer = newLayer
    }


    else {
        print("Long press ended")

        if let layer = layer {
            print("width is: \(layer.presentationLayer()?.bounds.width)")
            print("Total Width is \(self.view.bounds.width * 2)")
            pauseLayer(layer)
            layerHolder.append(layer)

            endPoint += (layer.presentationLayer()?.bounds.width)!
            print("endPoint is: \(endPoint)")
        }

    }


}


func pauseLayer(layer : CALayer){
    let pausedTime : CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime

}
```

So what I'm trying to do is get the width of the first CALayer, which I do with `layer.presentationLayer()?.bounds.width` and have that be the "x" point of the next CALayer that is created. The effect will look like it is one continuous bar, but really its a bunch of CALayers placed beside each other. This seems to be fine.

However, the issue is when the next CALayer is created it looks as if the width is set not to 0 (which I need it to be 0) but the length of all the CALayers. So it just pops into view and then starts animating. I've been trying to figure out why for hours, can someone help please!?

**UPDATE**: I believe the reason to why its doubling is because the `layer.presentationLayer()?.bounds.width` is not being reseted to 0 so its always being added to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this updated code:

```
        //Global Variables
    var layer: CALayer?
    var holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
    var nextXOffset = CGFloat(0.0)


    func setUpView(){

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)
        holdGesture.addTarget(self, action:"handleLongPress:")

    }

    func handleLongPress(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

        if(sender.state == .Began) {

            let newLayer = CALayer()
            newLayer.frame = CGRect(x: nextXOffset, y: 0, width: 0, height: 10)
            newLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

            animation.fromValue = 0
            animation.toValue = self.view.bounds.width * 2 - nextXOffset
            animation.duration = 5
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)

            print("Long Press Began")
            newLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "bounds.size.width")

            layer = newLayer
        }
        else {
            print("Long press ended")

            if let layer = layer {

                pauseLayer(layer)
                layer.frame = layer.presentationLayer()!.frame
                nextXOffset = CGRectGetMaxX(layer.frame)
//                layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }
    }

    func pauseLayer(layer : CALayer){
        let pausedTime : CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
        layer.speed = 0.0
        layer.timeOffset = pausedTime

    }
```

Comment: AND HE DOES IT AGAIN LADIES AND GENTLEMEN!

Comment: Hey Arun, is there a way to check if the right side of the layer has touched the right of the screen. Basically, when the bar is full(reaching from left to right), i need to stop the animation and call a function.

Comment: if nextXOffset >= self.view.bounds.width * 2

Comment: oh really! And where do i implement that??

Comment: After this line:                 nextXOffset = CGRectGetMaxX(layer.frame)

Comment: Oh gotcha! But I need to track if the bar is full while the user is holding down on the screen, not after they let go. Does that make sense?